# How to extract a pattern of letters from a string?

Tags: dart

I have a String 'baseball' and I want to loop on this string and print the output like this:
'b',
'ba',
'bas',
'base',
'baseb',
'baseba',
'basebal',
'baseball'

Comment: Use mid() and set the start and end points so they increment.

Answer (score 1):

Just loop through the string and concat the letters and print the result.

```
            String str = "baseball";
            String output = "";
            for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
              output += str[i];
              print(output);
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd create the incremental substrings. If you want to reuse the functionality, perhaps make it a synchronous generator:

```dart
Iterable<String> prefixes(String string, {int minLength = 1}) sync* {
  for (var i = minLength; i <= string.length; i++) {
    yield string.substring(0, i);
  }
}
```

Then you can print them as you want:

```dart
  for (var prefix in prefixes("baseball")) {
    print(prefix);
  }
```